# Why does Heisenberg’s Uncertainty Principle not take wavelength into account?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In class today we were taught about Heisenberg’s equation, $\Delta x\Delta p\ge\frac{h}{4\pi}$.

Why isn’t De Broglie wavelength a factor here - or is it, but it’s represented behind the deltas instead? After all, if we’re dealing with indeterminism, isn’t that where the wave part of particle-wave duality comes into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was precisely De Broglie who hypothesized that $p=h/\lambda$. So you can also write $\Delta x / \Delta \lambda = 1/4\pi$.

Comment: *facepalm* I should have been able to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, what is $\lambda$ here? I suppose it would be something like $\frac{\Delta x\Delta \lambda}{\langle \lambda \rangle^2}$ instead of $\frac{\Delta x}{\lambda}$.

Comment: @Dvij Where do you get your first fraction from? This answer seems to flow quite nicely from De Broglie’s equation $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$.

Comment: I corrected my answer after @DvijMankad 's comment